# Using showModalDialog and then wanting to be able to select text from resulting dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, showmodaldialog

I am using `window.showModalDialog('../common/poe_details.jsp','self','dialogHeight:450px;dialogWidth:900px;status=0;scroll=yes');`
in my application. Now the problem is that i could not select text from resulting showModalDialog.
And i want to select and copy text from this showModalDialog. Any help regarding this issue or any alternate solotion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to do, but you would have a lot more control if you used a jQuery modal dialog instead of a "real" popup window. Example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-form.html

This way, the popup and the main page are really one page, so it all runs together.